# Javascript - is it possible to make a loop using functions?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to make a loop but without using built in Javascript loops like while, for and do?  Also I would like to avoid recursion to save memory.

I imagine it would involve cleverly calling a function, letting it drop out and then calling it again until the condition is met.

edit: added example

```
var i = 0;
var condition = false;
function loop() {
    i++;
    if (i >= 3) {
        condition = true;
    }
}
loop(); //somehow keep calling until condition is met.
```

Comment: To call a function, exit, then call it again, you would need... a loop.

Comment: you mean like `array.forEach()`?

Comment: Or are you asking about something like generators in other languages?

Comment: Please clarify your question, showing how you would like to use this looping feature? Your question is currently too vague to give a good answer.

Comment: Perhaps you want a timer? If you are doing it synchronously, no reason not to use a loop.

Comment: What is the issue with this question? Why was it closed?

Comment: It's a simple question really.  I'll take "no" as an answer as long as good reasons are given.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11550814/2627243

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can repeat some code with a recursive timer function:

```
(function repeat(n){
  if (!n) return;
  console.log("do something");
  setTimeout(repeat, 0, n-1);
})(4);
```

Contrary to a (non tail optimized) recursion, there's no cumulative memory consumption here.
This kind of construct is useful in some cases. But just avoiding the `for` and `while` keywords doesn't strike as one of them.

Comment: This looks like a textbook example of recursion.

Comment: From the question: *"Also I would like to avoid recursion to save memory."*

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  I wanted a function that rerun without cumulative memory consumption.